# A value of type 'num' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'

Tags: dart

I am getting error : "A value of type 'num' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'."
while executing this code. I got the fix. Just wanted to know why this error. Also Do we need to add "!" for every variable operation?

```
void main() {  
  Map <int, int> val = {1:10};
  int k = val[1]+5;
  //int k = val[1]!+5; //fix
}
```

o/p dart pad:

```
Error compiling to JavaScript:
Info: Compiling with sound null safety
Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:dartpad_sample/main.dart'.
lib/main.dart:3:17:
Error: Operator '+' cannot be called on 'int?' because it is potentially null.
  int k = val[1]+5;
                ^
lib/main.dart:3:17:
Error: A value of type 'num' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
  int k = val[1]+5;
                ^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

Comment: The `[]` operator on `Map<K, V>` returns a `V?` (because the key might not be in the map, in which case it returns `null` for mainly historical reasons). That's why you can't do `val[1] + 5`, because with null safety, you're not allowed to call `+` on `null`.
The `num` error seems like a spurious follow-up error, though. I'd fix the real error and hope it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a not null operator (!) in line 3 as shown

```
void main() {  
  Map <int, int> val = {1:10};
  int k = val[1]!+5;
  print(k);
}
```

no issue was raised during execution, please lmk if the issue is still faced.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. My question is:
so do we need to put "!" in every single expression?
What is "num" in the code? Error says "A value of type 'num' can't be assigned "
, All variables are type int .

Comment: Is this the whole code? please share a snapshot of console as well.

Comment: Why don't you try changing `Map<int,int>` to `Map<int,dynamic>`

Comment: I can change to  dynamic, I am trying to understand why its not working with int,  we are not using any other data type but int.  you can run it in dartpad.

Comment: Executing my code gives output "" ?

Comment: have a look in the docs. https://dart.dev/guides/language/numbers